# Dropping lists using pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have the following list of lists.

```
 data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 3}}
```

I want to drop all the lists with `0` as the 3rd entry i.e. `{m,n,0}`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy (but probably not the fastest) way:

```
DeleteCases[data, {_, _, 0}]
```

> `{{2, 0, 1}, {5, 0, 3}}`

This might be a bit faster for longer lists as it entirely avoids pattern matching:

```
Delete[data, Partition[Random`Private`PositionsOf[data[[All, 3]], 0], 1]]
```

Here a speed test:

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {1000000, 3}];
a = DeleteCases[data, {_, _, 0}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Delete[data, Partition[Random`Private`PositionsOf[data[[All, 3]], 0], 1]]; // 
   AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> `0.407339`
>
> `0.027375`
>
> `True`

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 3}}
Pick[data, Unitize@data[[;; , 3]], 1]
```

> {{2, 0, 1}, {5, 0, 3}}

And a timing comparison to `DeleteCases`

```
SeedRandom[1234]
Block[
 {data = RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {1000000, 3}], times, m1, m2},
 times = {
  AbsoluteTiming[m1 = DeleteCases[data, {__, 0}]][[1]],
  AbsoluteTiming[m2 = Pick[#, Unitize@#[[;; , 3]], 1] &@data][[1]]
 };
 {times, m1 == m2}
]
```

> {{0.403632, 0.031339}, True}